# Does the X-Pro 1's "Lens Focal Length Setting" do anything with automatic lenses?

Tags: focal-length, fujifilm, camera-settings, fujifilm-xpro1

In the X-Pro 1's custom menu, one of the options is `Focal Length Setting`. The manual says:

> FOCAL LENGTH SETTING (Defaults to 50mm)
>
> Enter lens focal length when using a lens that does not supply the focal length to the camera. Choose from LENS 1 (21 mm),
>   LENS 2 (24 mm), LENS 3 (28 mm), LENS 4 (35 mm), LENS 5 (50 mm), and LENS 6 (75 mm).

With the 35mm normal lens attached, this says 50mm. I don't have any other lenses to test with, but my impression here is that this setting is just left at the default and ignored when using an XF mount lens with electronic coupling. However, [some people say otherwise](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/read.asp?forum=1020&message=41322190) — that the value is at 50mm because that's the closest standard value to the effective focal length of the lens.

I think they're just wrong, but since multiple viewpoints are out there I wanted to be sure. Does this setting have any effect whatsoever when using an XF lens?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to say 21mm to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I have tried, and it lets me, but I can't see any apparent difference, but maybe there's something I'm missing. There's no image stabilization, so it's not that. I think the circumstantial evidence is pretty strongly on the "does nothing" side, but I find it weird that Fujifilm doesn't just gray out the option when an XF lens is mounted.

Comment: In Panasonic GF1 when I have my Lumix G 20mm attached the exif data has info about the Focal length(35mm format) as 41mm, so the camera compares the crop ratio that you get from a smaller sensor by adjusting the focal length info for the 35mm standard. I believe that something similar is happening with the X-Pro 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experimentation: **no, it doesn't do anything**. It's just there for the future, and it's just a UI quirk that it's not grayed-out.